# IBOutlet Nil in UITableViewCell .Xib file

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, nib, iboutlet

In my UITableViewCell sub class called Cell, all of the IBOutlets I attach from the corresponding Xib file are nil and result in the app crashing with the error *Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* on the line where I attempt to access a property of the IBOutlet. the File's Owner of the .Xib file is set to cell and so is the UITableViewCell in the .Xib file

Code:

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! (CONNECTED TO .XIB FILE)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    viewDidLoad()
    print(label.text)//APP CRASHES HERE!
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    return cell

}
```

}

Comment: Does it crash if you create separate function and print label.text there - call that function from cell for row at index path instead from awakeFromNib

Comment: yes, it does crash. Before posting this I created a function called ViewDidLoad and printed label.text in it. I then called viewDidLoad in awakeFromNib()

Comment: try to call if from cell for row at index path where you actually use your cell instead from awake from nib

Comment: @Miknash I just tried but the app still crashes

Comment: Check your custom class set in .xib file owner is your class "Cell"

Comment: @ShauketSheikh it is, I mentioned that in my original post

Comment: your inside view did not connected with your file owner , so make a iboutlet property     @IBOutlet private var contentView: UIView!
connect this with the main view of xib file as a refrence outlet

Comment: and inside this function  @objc required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        commonInit() // write this to load nib file
    }

Comment: inside this load your nib from bundle and add in your contentview as subview and set frame of your contentview addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds

Comment: @ShauketSheikh that worked, thank you!

Comment: let me add in answer then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174134/discussion-between-shauket-sheikh-and-lontronix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inside view did not connected with your file owner, so make a IBOutlet property.

`@IBOutlet private var contentView: UIView!`

connect this with the main view of xib file as a refrence outlet.

and inside this function of your custom class

`@objc required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder)! commonInit() // write this to load nib file }`

in `commonInit()` load your nib from bundle and add your **contentview** as commonInit()